# New to Electron. How would i set up an event listener for a button in a browserwindow document?

Tags: javascript, electron

I have an html file containing a div, with the id "button".

In my main.js file, i have: win = new BrowserWindow() and win.loadFile(htmlURL).

How would i send an event to the javascript file when the button is clicked? (For example, print out "clicked")

Comment: Create a new script file and connect it to the HTML file using `<script src="new_script_file.js"></script>` like you do with normal HTML files

Comment: i think i found my answer here, sort of: https://pasteboard.co/JDfJsVo.png I have yet to test though.